# Lightweight javascript editor for textarea

Tags: javascript, looking-for-a-script, text-editor

I'm looking for a simple javascript editor, much like the one i'm using to type this message. I've tried searching (and i wondered why starting to ask a question shows much better search results than just searching) and have come up with a few results, none of them relevant.

I just need a very simple editor, that displays text as `<p>`, has a way to insert links, and allows me to display html tags in the text rather than making them get parsed.
The editors that I've seen so far all have a rich feature set and more functions than i would ever want, or want to learn to use.

Comment: Since John added a tag... how hard would it be to implement an editor from scratch with just a few buttons (add link, image, add code (that would allow me to add html tags that would be displayed without being interpreted) ? (i'm fairly good with php/css/html, have literally no experience with javascript though)

Comment: Not meant to be blunt, but it would be F***ING HARD. Consider reinventing **the very concept of cursor** over **6** different rendering engines. For a start. Or... meddling with never standardized editing frameworks and their shortcomings. And on.

Comment: I do not want to reinvent anything at all. I just want a (very) simple javascript editor like the ones that are on millions of websites. just that i don't care much for most of the functionality. I just need about 2 buttons out of the anywhere between 10 and 100 buttons that most of them have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one used to type this message is a custom version of [WMD](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/what-html-editor-is-used-by-stack-overflow). I've used [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) and although it does have a lot of features, you can specify which buttons to include in the configuration, so you can only have those few if you want.

(As to why asking gives you better search results: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool)

Comment: why can such a simple editor be so complicated, also i don't really wanna mess with markup right now.... also to the questions.... i actually tried searching for the exact string of my question and still didn't get as good results, it's interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The *simple* editor you see around is always **TinyMCE** in some dumbed down form.

Alternatives are [**xinha**](http://trac.xinha.org/) and [**ckeditor**](http://ckeditor.com/)

They both usually sport **more** functionality, but maybe they suit your taste better.

Wikipedia/Mediawiki should be using [**MeanEditor**](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMeanEditor) if that's what you're after.
They also offer [*pointers to other similar editors*](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/WYSIWYG_editor) in various stages of production.